# $G$ is a finite group. $a,b\in G$ and that $\forall n\in \Bbb N$ : $(a^{-1}ba)^{n}=a^{-1}b^{n}a$ can I presume that $(aba^{-1})^{n}=ab^{n}a^{-1}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I don't know how to check it.
I can't assume that G is abelian so I can't use the axiom of commutativity.
$(aba^{-1})^{n}=ab^{n}a^{-1}$ is different.

Comment: $a=(a^{-1})^{-1}$

Comment: You don't even need to _assume_ the property in the question title -- it follows from the group axioms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both equalities hold in any group, by associativity.

$$(a^{-1} b a)^n = (a^{-1} b a)(a^{-1} b a) \cdots (a^{-1} b a) = a^{-1} b^n a$$

$$(aba^{-1})^n = (aba^{-1})(aba^{-1})\cdots(aba^{-1}) = ab^n a^{-1}$$